# XPath not working on server

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm writing some XPath queries which work just fine on my localhost, running PHP 5.3.24, but even the simplest XPath test won't work on my production server, running PHP 5.3.3.

I'm running this query:

```
$table = $xpath->query("div[@class='info-column']");
```

And getting the following result (on `die(print_r($table));`):

```
DOMNodeList Object ( ) 1
```

On localhost, I get all the information from the HTML within.

Is there incompatibility in some PHP versions or did I miss any configurations?

Comment: Where are you getting the (HTML) input from, and how does it look like?

Comment: A regular string variable. I even tested the simplest HTML on the server, something like:

`<div id="GoingPrices" class="info-column">
              <div class="heading-block">
                <div class="head">
                  <h2>
                    <div></div>Going,
                    <strong>Bold</strong></h2>
                  <h3>Title</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
  </div>`

Comment: Can you please post the code that is not working on your web server as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)? So complete code that we can run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `<?php

echo '<pre>';

$html = '
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MyTitle</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="myclass">
     <h2>My Title</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = $xpath->query("//div[@class='myclass']")->item(0);
print_r($query);

echo '</pre>';

?>`

Answer (score 0):

In some older versions (I do not know when the behavior changed, and a quick grep through the changelog didn't result in any enlightenment) PHP does not expose `DOMNode`'s class members to `var_dump(...)` and `print_r(...)`.

You will have to dump a specific field, eg. the node name:

```
print_r($query->nodeName);
```